# Data is not being written to CSV file

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to write fields from a database table to a csv file but nothing is being written to the file before it downloads. I've searched online for any answers that may be helpful but I cannot find any. What I am trying to do is use PHP's SPLFileObject to write data from a database table to a csv file but like I said, it is not writing the data from the table to the file. Any help that could fix this issue would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
 public function indexAction()
 {
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=reports.csv');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header("Expires: 0");

    $this->getExportService()->exportToCSVFile();

    exit;
 }



 /**
     * Setter method
     * @return ExportModel
     */
    public function set()
    {
        $this->spl_file = new SplFileObject(self::CSV_FILENAME, "w");

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Getter method
     * @return SplFileObject|null
     */
    public function get()
    {
        return $this->spl_file;
    }

     public function exportToCSVFile()
     {
       // get the fields from the order_records table

       $rows = $this->table->select();


       foreach ($rows as $fields) {
           $this->get()->fputcsv(array('id' => $fields->id, 'date' => $fields->date, 'status' => $fields->status,
               'payment_status' => $fields->payment_status, 'campaign_id' => $fields->campaign_id, 'tax' => $fields->tax,
               'shipping' => $fields->shipping, 'payment_method' => $fields->payment_method, 'buyer_email' => $fields->buyer_email,
               'paypal_payment_id' => $fields->paypal_payment_id, 'paypal_payer_id' => $fields->paypal_payer_id, 
               'buyer_name' => $fields->buyer_name, 'paypal_capture_id' => $fields->paypal_capture_id,
               'paypal_authorization_id' => $fields->paypal_authorization_id
           ));
       }
    }
```

Comment: Just a wild guess, but I'll bet the problem is that you're filling an object in memory but you're not doing anything with it.  After it's been filled, you're going to have to write it to the output somehow.

Comment: wouldn't fputscv do it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that library (or PHP for that matter), but the trend is that you construct a file in memory or on the disk and then you spit it out to some output stream with the proper headers and the browser will download (or open if it is a file format supported by the browser such as pdf).  If this SplFileObject does this, then at the very  least you need to pass some sort of stream to it.  Otherwise how does it know where to put the output?

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: I've checked the logs, it's not saying anything about it..